# layout of application changes in other android phones

Tags: android, xml, layout

here is my code. This same code is installed in many device and layout is not same in all.I have used relative layout and have drag and drop object. But even if you dragand drop object, the code should work finely in all devices.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/room1"
    android:background="@drawable/room1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/load"
     android:background="@drawable/load1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About"
    android:id="@+id/appbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView10" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/employee"
    android:background="@drawable/employee"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Message to all members"
    android:id="@+id/allmessage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/appbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/status"
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/employee"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/employee" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="FAMILY"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:textColor="#018F99"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emergency"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emergency"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="EMERGENCY"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emergency"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="LOADSHEDDING\n     SCHEDULE"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/appbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#020202" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/room2"
    android:background="@drawable/room2click"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/emergency"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gate"
    android:background="@drawable/gateclick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/appbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/homeautomation1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/appbutton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/appbutton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: check the images. I have added them too. please give me a very detailed answer. will appericiate thanks

Comment: Firstly, post your entire xml layout. The code above is missing the root layout tag if not more.

Comment: Where is the relative layout you have used?

Comment: use root layout as linear layout instead of relative layout ......

Comment: don't use drag and drop in android but you still want to use drag and drop, please use Constrain Layout feature of new Android studio 2.2 . This is under development and may have some bug  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because every device has different resolution and PPI. So basically there are numerous ways in which you can achieve the required task. 
1) Use Linear Layout and try "weight". It will divide the screen into various portions and layout won't effect on another device.
2) Use different layout files.(Like earlier we do in eclipse)
3) use different files for values.xml
4) There is a custom library called "sdp" which will the do task automatically for you. Just search over the internet about it.